# Why am i requiring to return again inside the higher order function

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

Been looking into some `decorators` in python3. Below is a code snippet. Why am i required to return the function (`fn`), when it is called inside the `wrapper` function

```
from functools import wraps

def log_function_data(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(fn.__name__)
        print(fn.__doc__)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)   #why am i returning this?
    return wrapper

@log_function_data
def add(x,y):
    '''Adds 2 numbers and returns'''
    return x + y
```

The `add` function is already returning the result of the operation. So i call the add function without the `decorator` the return works like:

```
def add(x,y):
    '''Adds 2 numbers and returns'''
    return x + y

result = add(2,3) ##have the result = 5
```

Comment: Marking down a question, with no comments is a shame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # why am i returning this?
> ```

Please consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-20).
Python interprets your code at distinct times:

1. once, at [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) time (when we generate bytecode for functions)
2. repeatedly, at run time (when you call the function)

You could choose not to `return fn`, but that would cause an important change to the generated bytecode, resulting in a decorated function which returns the default value of `None`. Since the generated bytecode wouldn't even bother calling `add()`, it's hard to call the final result a "decorated" function at all, it's more like a completely different function that ignored the `fn` passed into it.

To better understand decoratoring, you might find it instructive to play around with [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). I recommend making a one-line change in your source code, and noticing the diff's between the variant bytecodes.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you know someone that is extremely good at maths. Imagine this girl, **Alice**, is so good that she is the only person in the world that could solve problem **X**.

There is a catch here, Alice only speaks French, but the problem X is explained in any randomly picked language and is also expected to be answered in that same language. Sadly, there is no way for her to interpret problem X in any other language than french.

Imagine you are interested in solving problem X. You think about it 2 minutes and come to a solution:

> I know Alice, she has the math part and I know Bernard, he can
>   translate from any language to French and back at perfection. Let's make
>   them work together to solve problem X!

The algorithm they will use to work is the following:

1. Bernard reads problem X and translated it in French
2. Alice solves the French version of X
3. Bernard translates Alice's answer back in the original language
4. Return a solution

In python, this look like this:

```py
def main():

  insane_translator = Bernard()

  def attach_translator(french_solver):

      def translation_decorator(X):
          french_X = insane_translator.translate(X, input_lang=X.lang, output="fr")
          french_solution = french_solver(french_X)
          solution = insane_translator.translate(french_solution, input_lang="fr", output=X.lang)
          return solution

      return translation_decorator

  x = X()
  solve = attach_translator(Alice.solve)
  solution = solve(x)
  print(solution)

class Alice:
    @staticmethod
    def solve(french_X):
        # Do some incredible things using french_X, Alice is a genius.
        return french_X + " 42"

class Bernard:
    def translate(self, text, input_lang=None, output=None):
        # Translate from any input language to any output language, Bernard is insane!
        return f"from {input_lang} to {output} of: \n\t{text}"

class X:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lang = "Alien"

  def __str__(self):
    return "\tProblem definition"


main()
```

Bernard is used as a translator to "decorate" alice's working power. If you don't call `fn` that means that you don't ask Alice to work, you are therefore only translating back and forth with no benefit. The goal of the decorator is to add some treatment before and after the decorated function is called, the whole point is to call the function in a different way from what it was originally designed to be.